# Surrounding simple_form associations with td tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, simple-form

Okay so this is a pretty simple question but for the life of me I can't find this anywhere. I have found a bunch of things that come really close to what I need but nothing specific.

So here is my view:

```
<tbody>
    <% permissions.each do |permission| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=  permission.label %></td>
      <%= simple_form_for permission do |f| %>
      <%= f.association :roles, as: :check_boxes, label: false, label_method:  lambda { |p| "" }, fields_element: "<td>" %>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    <%= debug(permissions) %>    
  </tbody>
```

I am simply looking to put each of the roles in its own TD tag.  I have a feeling that the answer is so simple that nobody has bothered posting anything about it. Please help!

Comment: Someone posted an answer that said I should use wrapper_tag. However, I have tried this and it put a td tag around all the associated roles instead of each of them. When I mentioned this the answer was removed but I wanted to comment on it here so I didn't get the same answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  = f.association :roles, as: :check_boxes, item_wrapper_tag: :td
```

If you are using boostrap, add this option to the input: `boolean_style: :inline` according to https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/685#issuecomment-10184181

Comment: This works but causes a slight issue. I was using label_method:  lambda { |p| "" } to remove the label but now the labels return as "Role ids 1 / Role ids 2 etc etc" My new input looks like this <%= f.association :roles, as: :check_boxes, label: false, label_method:  lambda { |p| "" }, item_wrapper_tag: :td, boolean_style: :inline %>

Comment: It appears that `label_method`/`item_wrapper_tag` and `boolean_style: :inline` are incompatible. `boolean_style: :nested` will hide the labels, but ignore the :td tag.

Comment: I agree Leito. However, that only means I still have no answer. Its a catch 22 at this point. I either get the labels or no td tags.

Comment: Also, I have just realized...that in the current state of my checkboxes they can't be checked for some reason. I removed the boolean_style and item_wrapper_tag options and they became checkable again. **UPDATE** I Just found out that the reason they can't be checked is because the actual input is hidden and the span around it that shows the visual representation of the checkbox is placed inline just to the RIGHT of the hidden checkbox. So if I click to the left of the visible checkbox it clicks....

Comment: Using a real method as :label_method will work! Using `label_method: :name` will work. You could have a method that returns and empty string and use that. ===== Why they weren't checkable? it should be clear in the HTML, mine are working as expected. If I where you, I'll post an issue on Github issues, explaining the problem you are having in its minimum expression: `boolean_style: :inline, :item_wrapper_tag and :label_method with a lambda`. I'm sure they will point you on the right direction and if it's a bug you will have contributed to the project.

Comment: I have <%= f.association :roles, as: :check_boxes, label: false, label_method: :name, item_wrapper_tag: :td, boolean_style: :inline %> This won't work for me for two reasons. A) I dont want labels. I want empty labels and creating a method returning an empty string didnt work. B) The checkboxes dont get overlaid with the actualy hidden input as mentioned above